# After Adding .EDMX file to Windows Form Application, Type Name Does Not Exist Errors Occur

Tags: winforms

I am starting with a basic windows form application with a form and a button, no code yet. I then add an EDMX file and map it to a backend SQL Server Database. After adding the EDMX file, I get following errors:

> The type name 'Windows' does not exist in the type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.System'

It can no longer find 'Drawing' in System anymore either.

I then delete the EDMX file and all errors go away.

Very bizarre.

Comment: Check if the system dll is within the references.

Comment: This could be due to a different namespace or something, idk.

Comment: Its all there in the references: System, System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the tables in the SQL Server database was named "Systems". I renamed this table, updated the EDMX and the errors went away.